# Replace procedural approach with a set based approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that is called from an SSIS package several times with a different value as an argument. The stored procedure contains an open query to an SSRS cube, and returns a list of people. The resultset is stored in a temporary table.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (Person varchar(50), Cat1 bit, Cat2 bit, Cat3 bit, Cat4 bit, Cat5 bit)
INSERT INTO #tmp EXEC sys.sp_executesql @query

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT Person FROM #tmp WHERE ' + @Category + '= 1'
EXEC (@sqlCommand);
```

For each person in the resultset, there should be an insert to another table with some information. The information is the name of the person, some other static content, and a value which I can get from running another stored procedure and count the rows returned.

An example of an insert could be

```
     Name        Static info      @@rowcount   
+-------------++--------------++--------------+
|Homer Simpson||Something here||ValueFromCount|
+-------------++--------------++--------------+
```

As of now, I have a prewritten stored procedure that inserts a row to a the desired table, but it has a parameter which is the person name. I get the `@@rowcount` value by executing the other SP from the current SP (a bit nested but works fine).

I could easily use an SQL `WHILE` loop or a `CURSOR` for each person in the resultset, and call the insert SP, but I can't help to think that there must be a more efficient way of doing this!

The flow right now is

1. SSIS package executes the stored procedure that returns a list of persons
2. For each person in the list, execute the `SP_Insert_To_Table procedure`.

   2.1. From `SP_Insert_To_Table procedure`, execute `SP_Get_All_Actions` and select `@@rowcount` as the dynamic value to be inserted.

I have the idea that I might be able to join the result from the `#tmp` table with the count of actions the person has done, so that I would get a new resultset that could be inserted all in one, but I can't figure it out since the count is specific for each person in the list.

Is there a way to to this in a set based fashion instead of using a procedural approach?

Answer (score 0):

With no details to work with this is a bit challenging but it certainly sounds like removing the loop should be pretty straight forward. All I can do is rough pseudocode.

```
Insert into SomeTable (ColumnsListedHere)
from SomeOtherTable
join Something on some conditions
where SomeCriteria = GetListOfPerson
```

Comment: Yeah I'm obviously overthinking this. I some of your thoughts and I'm closing in on a solution!